# How to avoid long-running tasks when doing Spark cube

Tags: sql, apache-spark, query-optimization, cube

Imagine a weblog where each event is attributed with multiple dimensions (siteID, countryID, pageID, etc.) and also has a visitor ID:

```
eventID | siteID | countryID | pageID | visitorID
```

The goal is to count unique visitors for each combination of dimensions including totals (i.e. cube). It can be expressed as the following Spark SQL query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT(visitorID)) 
FROM weblog
   GROUP BY siteID, countryID, pageID WITH CUBE
```

Assuming that all dimension fields have relatively high cardinality, this sort of aggregation can be efficiently done by Spark because each combination of dimensions will receive a relatively small number of visitor IDs.

CUBE operation, however, creates heavy tasks that correspond to groupings like

```
... GROUP BY siteID, countryID
... GROUP BY siteID
etc.
```

These tasks receive a very high number of IDs (and task that computes the grand total receives all IDs in the entire log). It seems that Spark 2.2 is not able to parallelize it, so the job runtime is bounded by these long-running tasks.

How to optimize this sort of queries?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is don't use `COUNT(DISTINCT(_))`. You just cannot have a cake and eat it to. You can either have exact results, which can result in skews and failures, or reasonable approximations with bounded precision and predictable performance.

Instead use approximate counts distinct using sketch.

```
SELECT approx_count_distinct(visitorID)
FROM ...
GROUP BY ... WITH CUBE
```

Comment: Well, in a simple case it is possible to optimize exact counting. For instance, one can add a partitioning column

  `bucket = hash(visitorID)`

to split visitor IDs into disjoint sets and then do something like that:

`
SELECT 
  SUM(count)
FROM (
    SELECT
      siteID, 
      countryID, 
      pageID
      COUNT(DISTINCT(visitorID)) as count
    GROUP BY siteID, countryID, pageID, bucket
  )  
GROUP BY siteID, countryID, pageID
`

but it is very difficult to manage in complex real-life queries